# How do you use (get values from keys, add items) Hashtables in F#

Tags: f#, hashtable

I would like to know how to use a `System.Collections.Hashtable` in F#.  The reason it is a Hashtable is because I am referencing C# assemblies.

How would I call the following methods?
 - Add
 - Get value from key

I have not been able to find anything useful in Google about this.

Comment: You may want to consider using a generic Dictionary, which gives you type-safety for the hashtable. Usage is just like described in the present answers. Also, there is a built-in map type in F#, if you want to stay within the language.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As Mark points out, you can work with the `Hashtable` type directly from F# (just like with any other .NET type). The syntax for accessing indexers in F# is slightly different though:

```
open System.Collections 

// 'new' is optional, but I would use it here
let ht = new Hashtable()
// Adding element can be done using the C#-like syntax
ht.Add(1, "One")  
// To call the indexer, you would use similar syntax as in C#
// with the exception that there needst to be a '.' (dot)
let sObj = ht.[1]
```

Since Hashtable is not generic, you would probably want to cast the object back to string. To do that, you can either use the `:?>` downcast operator, or you can use the `unbox` keyword and provide a type annotation to specify what type do you want to get as the result:

```
let s = (sObj :?> string)
let (s:string) = unbox sObj
```

If you have any control over what type is used, then I would recommend using `Dictionary<int, string>` instead of `Hashtable`. This is fully compatible with C# and you would avoid the need to do casting. If you're returning this as a result from F#, you could also use standard F# `map` and just upcast it to `IDictionary<_,_>` before passing it to C#:

```
let map = Map.empty |> Map.add 1 "one"
let res = map :> IDictionary<_, _>
```

This way, C# users will see a familiar type, but you can write the code in the usual functional style.

Comment: THanks, the upcast and .[""] syntax helped me resolve it.  The trick was taking the obj dict[] to a Hashtable dict[].  :)

Comment: Isn't :> the upcast operator? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233220.aspx

Comment: @Artefacto: Yes, you're right. I'll correct the answer (hopefuly I'll eventualy remember which one is which...).

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty straightforward to do.

```
open System.Collections //using System.Collections

let ht = Hashtable() // var ht = new Hashtable()

ht.Add(1, "One")

let getValue = ht.Item[1] // var getValue = ht[1];
//NB: All indexer properties are named "Item" in F#.
```

Comment: If you wanted to call `Item` directly, then the syntax would be `ht.Item(1)`. However, it is possible to access indexers directly from F# using `ht.[1]`.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. As you can tell, I've only just started with F#.

Comment: No problem. Welcome and have fun learning F#! The language has been changing quite a bit during the finalization of VS 2010 - there were times when you had to use `Item` explicitly, so information on the internet can be sometimes confusing :-).

Comment: Thanks guys, it would be nice for the .Net collections to be accessible in the same way as native F# collections. Maybe you can and I am still not practiced enough.