# Convert a F# map to a Hashtable

Tags: f#, dictionary, hashtable

I need to convert a F# map class to a System.Collections.Hashtable for use by C#.

This question is not the same as the following:
[How do you use (get values from keys, add items) Hashtables in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032298/how-do-you-use-get-values-from-keys-add-items-hashtables-in-f)

That question asked how to return values from a hashtable. I want to build an F# map and then convert it to a System.Collections.Hashtable.

How do I do this?

Thanks very much.

Here is what I have tried (does not compile):

```
#light

open System
open System.Collections
open System.Collections.Generic

let my_map = dict [(1, "one"); (2, "two")]


let myHash = Hashtable()
my_map |> Map.iter (fun k v -> myHash.Add(k, v) )
```

*Edit*: Thanks for your answers.  Here is what I decided to use:

```
let my_map = Map [(1, "one"); (2, "two")]

let myHash = Hashtable()
my_map |> Map.iter (fun k v -> myHash.Add(k, v))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code compiles.

```
let my_map = Map( [(1, "one"); (2, "two")] )

let myHash = Hashtable()

my_map |> Map.iter (fun k v -> myHash.Add(k, v) )
```

The original one does not compile because the type of `dict [(1, "one"); (2, "two")]`  is `IDictionary<int, string>`, not `Map`. And Map.* function family require to operate on F# Map type.

Answer (score 5):

If I was writing this, I would probably prefer `for` loop instead of higher-order function `iter`. You are writing imperative code (to deal with imperative objects) anyway and I don't think that using `iter` makes it "more functional". F# provides support for imperative programming as well, so we can use those imperative features in this case:

```
let myHash = Hashtable() 
for (KeyValue(k, v)) in myMap do
  myHash.Add(k, v)
```

I usually prefer `iter` function only when I don't need to write explicit lambda function as the second parameter. For example if the following would work:

```
myMap |> Seq.iter myHash.Add // This doesn't work, so I prefer 'for' instead
```

If you have some control over the C# code, you could also consider just using `IDictionary<'K, 'V>` in C# instead of `Hashtable`. In that case, you could easily pass F# `Map<'K, 'V>` as the result, because map implements the `IDictionary<'K, 'V>` interface (exactly to allow smooth use from C#).

Answer (score 4):

you can use active pattern KeyValuePair

```
my_map |> Seq.iter(fun (KeyValue (k,v)) -> myHash.Add(k, v))
```